# how to validate login username and password for Sharepoint using sharepoint web service from ios?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

i am using sharepoint webservice for an ipad application. i am sending the credentials required to login to the sharepoint along with the SOAP request. but the problem is when i send wrong username or password it the web service does not throw up any authentication error. instead it gives an html error page as a response. how to validate login credentials?

Comment: How are you sending the credentials to the Web Service, and which Web Service(s) operation(s) are you calling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try checking the http response code for that error page. Are you using NSURL... or ASIHTTP, etc? Here's how you get ot the headers in NSHTTPURLResponse:

```
NSHTTPURLResponse *r = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
NSDictionary *dict = [r allHeaderFields];
```

Comment: thanks it worked. i have checked it with the status code from the response.

Comment: Once the login is true i have to push another view controller. presently i have written it in the connectiondidfinishloading method. is that the appropriate place or is there a better way??

Comment: That could work, but optimally you should have a separate class handle this functionality to encapsulate it if you need to use it somewhere else. You could then create a @protocol in that class, and implement a delegate function called after connectiondidfinishloading. That implemented function in your vc would do the push.

Comment: Thanks i have implemented it through delegate. But i also need to know whether maintaining all the soap request and web service call in the view controller itself or should i separate it in a different class.